# Trouble with multicolumns

Tags: enumerate, multicol

I am trying to adjust my columns. Two verses have to be in the left column, one in the right column. What is the solution?

Thank you in advance.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
\newcommand{\fixspacing}{\vspace{0pt plus 1filll}\mbox{}}
\begin{document}
\raggedcolumns
\begin{multicols}{2}
  \begin{enumerate}
\item O steh' uns, Sündern, bei, \\
hab' auf das Flehen Acht, \\
verleihe uns'ren Herzen Licht \\
am Ende dieser Nacht.

\item O, von der Sünde, schlau \\
und neidisch, mach uns frei, \\
es geh' an un'rem Herz das Netz \\ 
von Lug und Trug vorbei.

\item O, nimm doch weg die Furcht \\
vor Feinden von dem Land. \\
Erleuchte, die hier wohnen, dass \\
das Dunkel werd' gebannt. 
  \end{enumerate}
  \fixspacing
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image: This is what I get now:]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `\columnbreak` before the third `\item`.

Comment: Life should be that simple more often! 
Thank you very much.